# Using ampersand inside theme wrapped code (SASS)

Tags: css, sass, styling

I have got the following style:

```
.black-theme, .light-theme {
   .popup {
     $root: &;
     color: red;
     &--red {
       #{$root}__close-button {
         fill: red;
       }
     }
   }
}
```

It is generated to:

```
.black-theme .popup--red .black-theme .popup, .black-theme .popup--red .light-theme .popup__close-button, .light-theme .popup--red .black-theme .popup, .light-theme .popup--red .light-theme .popup__close-button {
  fill: red;
}
```

How to fix it and got the right code:

```
.black-theme .popup--red .popup__close-button, .light-theme .popup--red .popup__close-button {
  fill: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use this approach. & is a sass list of lists referencing to all the parent elements for the current selector, so you can use all the list functions on & and easily get the nth child of & of your choice (in this case de second one):

```
.black-theme, .light-theme {
    .popup {
        $root: nth(nth(&, 1), 2); // Get just the second selector: .popup
        color: red;
        &--red {
            #{$root}__close-button {
                fill: red;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Nice solution! And I suppose it could be more better by wrapping `nth(nth(&, 1), 2)` into function. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

how about:

```
.black-theme, .light-theme {
   .popup {
     $root: '.popup';
     color: red;
     &--red {
       #{$root}__close-button {
         fill: red;
       }
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: This is the first solution that I invented to solve my problem, but I supposed that it is too weird, because me need to duplicate class names in two places. Anyway, thank you for your answer!